# GradientTape returns None

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to use grad-CAM (I'm following this https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/03/09/grad-cam-visualize-class-activation-maps-with-keras-tensorflow-and-deep-learning/ from PyImageSearch) on a CNN I'm using transfer learning on.

In particular, I am using a simple CNN for a regression problem. I used MobileNetV2 with an Average Pooling layer and a Dense layer with one unit on top, as shown below:

```
base_model = MobileNetV2(include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3), weights='imagenet')
base_model.trainable = False
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))
x = base_model(inputs)
x = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="linear")(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

and the summary is:

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)         [(None, 224, 224, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
mobilenetv2_1.00_224 (Model) (None, 7, 7, 1280)        2257984   
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling2d (Gl (None, 1280)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 1)                 1281      
=================================================================
Total params: 2,259,265
Trainable params: 1,281
Non-trainable params: 2,257,984
_________________________________________________________________
```

I initialize the CAM object with:

```
pred = 0.35
cam = GradCAM(model, pred, layerName='input_2')
```

where pred is the predicted output on which I want to inspect the CAM and I also specify the layer name in order to refer to the input layer. Then I compute the heatmap on a sample image "img":

```
heatmap = cam.compute_heatmap(img)
```

Now, let's focus on a part of the implementation of the function compute_heatmap from PyImageSearch:

```
# record operations for automatic differentiation
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    # cast the image tensor to a float-32 data type, pass the
    # image through the gradient model, and grab the loss
    # associated with the specific class index
    inputs = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
    (convOutputs, predictions) = gradModel(inputs)
    # loss = predictions[:, self.classIdx]  # original from PyImageSearch
    loss = predictions[:]  # modified by me as I have only 1 output unit

# use automatic differentiation to compute the gradients
grads = tape.gradient(loss, convOutputs)
```

The problem here is that the gradient grads is None.

I thought that maybe the problem could lie in the network structure (all goes fine when reproducing the example of the classification task from the website), but I can't figure out where is the problem with this network used for regression!

Could you please help me?

Comment: I am having the same problem. Have you worked it out?

Comment: @JamesChang I think I worked it out someway, but I can't remember now. But maybe, it can be linked either to a not proper layer linking or to Tensorflow's layer predefined names, but I'm not sure. Can you please try both these ways and let me know?

Comment: I think I'd better pose a new question.